# Yahoo webmail on mobile removes spaces between text buttons

Tags: html, iphone, email, yahoo

Yahoo on iPhone 4s Safari removes the spacing between text navigation buttons. Every email client tested has rendered the spaces correctly except for Yahoo in mobile Safari. This is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>ZZZZZZZZZ | XXXXXXXXX&hellip; </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ReadMsgBody{width: 100%;}
    .ExternalClass{width: 100%;}
    body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
    table {border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body><img src="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/1x1.dyn?0OEG61m7iL4JGh7Fv1KvQ-mjt=0" width=1 height=1  width="1" height="1" border="0"><table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr><td width="650"><table width="650" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <tr><td>
        <table width="650" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <tr>
            <td width="325" align="left" valign="bottom"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?O4Gupk-UIFStoz8g_FXuD=19211" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#040400;text-decoration:underline;line-height:20px;">XXXXXXXXXX&hellip; </a></td><td width="325" align="right" valign="bottom"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/t.d?bYGupk-UIFStoz=/@HTML_2PREVIEW_2LINK_0a=WCL4JeqxNRqx-4ctqli6ZBkO" style="color: #000000;font-family: arial; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: underline;">View in web browser</a></td></tr>
          </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td id="header" align="center" width="650"><table id="header" width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="650" style="padding-top:30px;">
   <table width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                 <td width="535" align="left"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?YYGupk-UIFStoz126b=123" width="535"><img border="0" style="display:block;color:#EC008C;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" src="../../images/content/dai/temp/438/MS_header_01.gif" width="535" height="75" alt="ZZZZZZZZZ" /></a>
  </td>
  <td width="115">
   <img border="0" style="display:block;" height="75" width="115" src="../../images/content/dai/temp/438/spacer.gif" alt="ZZZZZZZZZ" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="650">
   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="55" align="center">
    <tr style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family: arial; font-size: 17px;">
     <td align="center" height="35" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?V4Gupk-UIFStoz127k=133" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">Bestsellers</a></td>
     <td align="center" height="35" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?CYGupk-UIFStoz127h=143" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">Tops</a>
     </td>
     <td align="center" height="35" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?R4Gupk-UIFStoz127q=153" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">Bottoms</a>
     </td>
     <td align="center" height="35" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?HYGupk-UIFStoz1273=163" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">Sale</a>
     </td>
     <td align="center" height="35" style="padding:0;"><a href="http://link.email.XXXXX.com/u.d?BYGupk-UIFStoz127w=173" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000;">More</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table></td></tr>
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with setting the width of the table, as Digital explained, it is recommended to not define table cellpadding attribute in combination with inline CSS padding on the tds.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/

After removing cellpadding from the table and placing inline, the email renders fine in Yahoo and AOL:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you move the width from the td to the table and remove the cellpadding from the table?

I can't replicate the issue, but I get better results for rendering when I change the code to follow the above. It will make the table push out to the full width of the cell, but that is the correct way it should be built anyway. Reducing the table width to 560 gives you the same result as your code gives in terms of the padding on either side of the table.

Comment: Thanks Digital-Frankenstein, I assume you mean to move the width attribute from the tds to the table in order to force the width of the table. Just learned that Outlook.com renders the same as Yahoo. This could be isolated to any webmail clients on iPhone Safari. I'll test on iOS Chrome.

Comment: Shoot, sorry. Should have proofed after posting.
Fixed my answer

Comment: Thanks Digital, your method definitely helped! I took some advice from Campaign Monitor as well. Never combine table cellpadding with inline CSS padding. See link in answer.